# The covariant derivative satisfies $\frac{d}{dt}\left<v(t),w(t)\right>=\left<\frac{Dv}{dt}(t),w(t)\right>+\left<v(t),\frac{Dw}{dt}(t)\right>$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

Let $v,w$ vector fields along the curve $\alpha:I\rightarrow S$, where $S$ is a regular surface. I need to prove that $$\frac{d}{dt}\left<v(t),w(t)\right>=\left<\frac{Dv}{dt}(t),w(t)\right>+\left<v(t),\frac{Dw}{dt}(t)\right>.$$

What I tried:

Let $\mathbb{x}(u,v)$ a parametrization of $S$. So, we can write
$$w(t)=a\mathbb{x}_{u}+b\mathbb{x}_{v}, v(t)=c\mathbb{x}_{u}+d\mathbb{x}_{v}, $$
where $a,b,c,d$ are differentiable functions. So, we have

$$\left<v(t),w(t)\right>=ac+bd\implies \frac{d}{dt}\left<v(t),w(t)\right>=a'c+ac'+b'd+bd'. $$

Well, I don't know how to get the expressions for the covariant derivatives, since they are given by the Christofell symbols.

What can I do?

Comment: Certainly your formula for the inner product is wrong. You *do* want to use the product rule for the inner product of the two vector fields. But what is the  *definition* of the covariant derivative, before a formula with Christoffel symbols appears?

Comment: @TedShifrin what was my mistake?
$\mathbb{x}_{u},\mathbb{x}_{v}$ is a basis for $T_{p}(S)$. I'm using that $\frac{d}{dt}\left<f,g\right>=\left<f',g\right>+\left<f,g'\right>$.

And the definition of covariant derivative of the vector field $w(t) $ is the orthogonal projection of $\frac{dw}{dt}$ on the plane $T_{p}(S).$ What can I do from this?

Comment: Your formula for the inner product needs to have the entries of the first fundamental form in it to be correct ($x_u,x_v$ is NOT an orthonormal basis). But, yes, $Dw/dt$ is the orthogonal projection of $dw/dt$ onto the tangent plane. So what can you say about $\langle v,Dw/dt\rangle$ and $\langle v, dw/dt\rangle$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what can I say.
I drew, thought and tried to visualize, but there's something I'm not getting.

Comment: I know what that is. What is the definition of a vector field on $S$?

Comment: A map $w:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that, for all $p\in S$, $w(p)\in T_{p}(S).$

Comment: I got that $\frac{Dw}{dt}\in T_{p}(S),$ also $v$, but what can I say about its inner products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition is to remeber that $v(t),w(t)$ are vector fields tangents to the surface $S$. See that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left<v(t),w(t)\right>=\left<v'(t),w(t)\right>+\left<v(t),w'(t)\right>. $$
Not necessarily $v'$ and $w'$ are tangents to the surface $S$, so, write

$$v'(t)=\frac{Dv}{dt}(t)+v_{n}(t), $$
where $v_{n}(t)$ denotes the normal component of $v'(t)$ and $\frac{Dv}{dt}(t)$ is the tangencial component of $v'(t)$. So, $\left<v_{n}(t),w(t)\right>=0,$ since $v_{n}$ are orthogonal to $w$. So,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left<v(t),w(t)\right>=\left<v'(t),w(t)\right>+\left<v(t),w'(t)\right>=\left<\frac{Dv}{dt}+v_{n}(t),w(t)\right>+\left<v(t),\frac{Dw}{dt}+w_{n}(t)\right> \\
=\left<\frac{Dv}{dt},w(t)\right>+\left<v_{n},w(t)\right>+\left<v(t),\frac{Dw}{dt}\right>+\left<v(t),w_{n}(t)\right>=\left<\frac{Dv}{dt},w(t)\right>+\left<v(t),\frac{Dw}{dt}\right>. $$

Comment: This answer is great and straight to the point.